# Is it possible to get Facebook feed, likes and comments from a closed group that I own using the Facebook API + PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to build a web application that gets feed, likes and comments from a closed group that I own - using the Facebook API + PHP

I saw that I can get information using this Graph API interface, started reading the facebook docs and got to a point that I start thinking that I cant actually do that: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/

But still there is this: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed

and **I just cant find the function that gets the group feed!**
So maybe I'm just not working right and I'm missing something.

Although when running it on the Facebook API interface it does work! - (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/)

In older posts, a lot of stackoverflowers recommended me to use the Graph API+PHP and it's completely

[Facebook Group Feed PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945719/facebook-group-feed-php-sdk)

[Is it possible to get a facebook feed to a closed group that I belong to but do not own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816436/is-it-possible-to-get-a-facebook-feed-to-a-closed-group-that-i-belong-to-but-do)

This is my code for now, ready to work.

```
 <?php

    session_start();

  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
  require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );

  use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;


  $app_id = '1408050536103050';
  $app_secret = 'a866372f873730e703cdf0cb4521bd99';
  $redirect_url = 'http://localhost/test/YellowSpider/src/';

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $app_id, $app_secret );

  //helper for redirect
  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url); 

  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect(); //Processes the redirect data from Facebook, if present. Returns a FacebookSession or null.

  if ( isset($session) ){
    // Create request object, execute and capture responce 
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/15013584710049696319/feed'); //Represents a request that will be made against the Graph API.

    //From the response - get graph object
    $response = $request->execute(); //Returns a Facebook\FacebookResponse from this request, from which a strongly-typed result can be retrieved. 
                                     //Throws an exception if the request fails. If the error is returned from Facebook, 
                                     //as opposed to a networking issue, a Facebook\FacebookRequestException is thrown.

    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(); //Returns the result as a GraphObject. If specified, a strongly-typed subclass of GraphObject is returned.
    var_dump($graph);


    //use graph object methods to get user details
    //$name = $graph->getname();

    //echo "Hi $name";

  } 
  else {
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>'; 

  }


?>
```

this is what i get in the var dump:

```
object(Facebook\GraphObject)[4]
  protected 'backingData' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a missing token and permission definition.
This webpage has a simple example of how it suppose to look like:

http://www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4/